# OPA Rego function statement evaluation order

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

```
package play


exists(obj, a) {
   obj[a]
}


hello {
     exists(input, "department")
     contains(input["location"], "London")
}

world {        
    contains(input["location"], "London")
    exists(input, "department")    
}
```

> input = {
>       "department": "Eng",
>       "location": "London"  }

Above code matches only **hello**. Why **world** does not match even when the conditions are same, but order reversed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the statements does not matter. You've actually found [a bug](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/opa/issues/2084)!

If you change the example slightly so that `exists` is not called with `input` as the first argument but instead something like `exists(input.user, "department")` and then you update the input document to reflect that:

```
{"user": {"department": "Eng", "location": "London"}}
```

You'll observe the correct behaviour (e.g., `world { contains(input.user["location"], "London"); exists(input.user, "department") }`).

Comment: Thanks. Any other solutions possible (other than nesting object inside "user") ?  When will the bug be addressed ? We can update and retest.

Comment: The bug should get resolved in the next few days. Keep an eye out for 0.17.2.